# windows10でのrubyの環境構築の際の文字コードエラーの対処方法について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

現在rubyの環境構築をwindows10を使って試しているのですが以下の手順をして文字コード関係のエラー?に手こずっていて質問致しました｡

以下の順にインストール

ruby3.0.0
node.js
yarn
sqlite3
rails6.1.3

その後、`rails new app` をしてディレクトリに移動後に `rails webpacker:install` を実行したのですが以下のエラーが発生してしまいました。

```
Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/pathname.rb:50:in match? :invalid byte sequence in utf-8 (ArgumentError)
```

対処方法として以下のコードをcmdで試してみたのですが効果ありませんでした。

```
Encoding.default_external = 'UTFｰ8'
```

その他には使用しているwindows10のバージョンとインストールしたrubyのバージョンが違ってないかを確認しましたが合っていたので違いました。
どなたか分かる方がいましたらご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Railsのアプリがあるappフォルダーのフルパスの中にASCII以外の文字(平仮名や漢字等)が含まれていませんか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます

Answer (score 0):

Windowsの日本語版ではいわゆるCP932という文字コードをつかっており、ユーザー名などが日本語だと不整合が起きてエラーが発生します。
回避方法としては、システムの設定の地域ダイアログで「システムロケールの変更」で「ワールドワイド言語サポートでUnicode UTF-8を使用」にチェックを入れることです。
ただし、Windows上の日本語アプリが文字化けするので推奨しません

次善の策としては、WSL2(Windows Subsystem for Linux)上のUbubtuなどで環境を構築することです

Comment: windowsのcmdを確認すると 自分の名前(漢字)になっておりおそらくそれが思い当たるのですがまずはそこから見ていきます。